# Which code generation tools do you use?

Tags: code-generation

If you use one of course, which one?

- MyGeneration
- T4
- UML Transformation Tool (precise which one)
- ...
- All others not listed above since there are so many

Answer (score 35):

Do my hands count? :)

Comment: This was nice to read. :D

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse EMF and JET.

Comment: While JET is popular, it's also not very powerful. For example, OAW/XPand supports aspect templates, so you can extend or replace existing templates; it is also based on a meta-model. EMF uses JET for its code generation, whereas GMF uses OAW/XPand for its code generation; the latter is significantly easier to extend or modify.

Answer (score 3):

CodeSmith Studio - lots of great sample templates that work with it.

Comment: excellent tool - I gave up on T4 and went back to CodeSmith after T4 templates weren't able to be configured to pick a server/database/table as properties, rather than hardcoded in the template code...

Answer (score 2):

"Normal" code-gen tools I use that many people don't think about:

- Windows Forms designer
- XAML for WPF UIs
- LINQ to SQL

Other code gen tools that are obviously code gen in the project:

- ANTLR
- Custom tools I wrote such as one that turns an Excel spreadsheet (`File.xlsx`) into code (`File.g.cs`)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse [Xpand](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xpand) and [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/), also known as [openArchitectureWare](http://www.eclipse.org/workinggroups/oaw/).

Comment: openArchitectureWare exists no more, all subproject have become part of the Eclipse Modeling. The toolchain contain Xpand, Xtend, MWE and Xtext.

Comment: @Gabriel openArchitectureWare still exists as an Eclipse working group (see the link in my answer).

Comment: That is true, I just wanted to stress, that there is no software under that name.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to avoid code generation and generate dynamic functionality at runtime, using either C# DynamicMethods or C# Lambda Expressions... I prefer not to have generated code in my solutions...

Comment: why? you love typing all that boring, repetitive code manually?

Comment: It's only boring and repetitive if you're doing it wrong.

Comment: In the traditional app, there's an absolute TON of pretty boilerplate code -- why on earth would someone want to rewrite that every time?  Perhaps you work on something very specialized and/or new each time LorenVS?

Comment: @Charlie, not always your language of choice can abstract you from repetitive code and even if it can, it might not be practical for performance reasons.

Comment: Code generation has one important merit - you can see what you generate. But generally, metaprogramming and metaobject protocols should be the right way imho.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following code generators:

- [Visio Enterprise Architect](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/fx102144891033.aspx#3) for generating SQL scripts for creating and updating databases
- [NConstruct](http://www.nconstruct.com/) for generating NHibernate mapping files and sometimes for generating "first draft" of an application
- [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/default.aspx) for generating UI design files, project and solution files etc.
- [Jet Brains Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) for lots of code snippets, template based chunks of code etc.

I believe my productivity would be much lower without code generation tools. Code generators usually don't produce bugs in generated code so this is also a good reason to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I just started playing with the code generation features of Enterprise Architect.  It's nice having code generated from the model instead of the database layer, but unfortunately their code-gen tool is a bit unwieldy.  So far I've tweaked its C# template to produce bare-bones CSLA classes which at least saves me a lot of typing.

Answer (score 0):

Jeeves (discussed in Advanced Perl Programming).

I have a pre-build step in VS 2005 that executes Jeeves to produce source code "just in time" for compilation/linking.

Comment: What is Jeeves can't find any link ?

Comment: Do you have a copy of Jeeves?

Answer (score 0):

I often write code generation scripts in Python.  In the distant past I have also used Perl.  Either language is well-suited to the task.

Comment: Do you use python to generate python or something else ?

Comment: I use Python to generate Java.  It's worth noting that I am not generating classes from UML or anything like that; I am generating classes that contained large numbers of constants.  This meant that we load constant data using the classloader instead of reading it from a file, which allows us a speed boost (the embedded system we work on has a poorly-implemented version of the JVM; many base classes have to be avoided because of poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

[DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html)

Can be configured to read any style of specification language, and generate code including post-code generation optimization.

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work now.

Comment: Website was down temporarily.  Link works now.

Answer (score 0):

### I use for generating code from UML:

1. [Visual Paradigm for UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/)
2. [Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/downloads) + [UML plugin](http://netbeans.org/projects/uml)

### For editing/ generating GUI's:

1. Netbeans IDE
2. MS Visual Studio

### For anything else

Python (because I find it's just the quickest way to hack something together).

Answer (score 0):

i use own generator jUle

http://code.google.com/p/jule/